# Android (Java) get image height and width by Picasso

Tags: java, android, picasso, image-size

I am having problem with displaying images correctly in my application.

I would like the size of the imageView to adapt to the size of the image, so I need to read the height and width of the image downloaded from the server using Picasso.

I've tried various solutions from other threads on StackOverflow, but unfortunately none of them worked.

When I try to load an image like this, the onBitmapLoaded method does not start at all. Only method onPrepareLoad starts.

```
Picasso.get().load(url).into(new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

        ivImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
      
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

    }
});
```

How can I get the height and width of a downloaded image with Picasso?